# Magento 2.3.7 category page swatch render issue with ajax infinite scroll

Tags: configurable-swatches, category-page, magento2.3.7, ajax-pagination

When we come first time on the category page, the swatches is coming properly (on page load), but when we scroll down to see the next product collection (ajax loaded product collection on scroll event), the swatches are not coming. We are using Magento 2.3.7 version along with a custom readymade theme MGS_ClaueTheme. This theme provides us a feature of product infinite scroll instead of default pagination.

Can anyone help to figure out why the swatches are not coming over ajax loaded products ?

We have also observed that inside the theme, they have overrided the *swatch-renderer.js* file and *renderer.phtml* file. We also try to debug them. But our doubt is if the problem is in these file, then the swatches must not come on page load also. There must be something to do with ajax call.

When the swatches are not getting rendered, even then the parent div are present in the dom
`<div class="swatch-opt-68962"></div>`
But the inner content are not getting rendered. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

how did you decide I have the same problem

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/204073)

Answer (score 0):

i've encountered same problem in customized WeltPixel Pearl theme.
There are few steps, that I've done to fix it:

1. I moved content of `<script type="text/x-magento-init">`, which inits swatch-renderer.js, by doing inline `data-mage-init`. Code in your **renderer.phtml** should look something like this after doing so:

```
<div class="swatch-opt-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($productId) ?>"
     data-role="swatch-option-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($productId) ?>"
     data-mage-init='{"Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer": 
        {"selectorProduct": ".product-item-details",
        "onlySwatches": true,
        "enableControlLabel": false,
        "numberToShow": <?=  $block->escapeJs($block->getNumberSwatchesPerProduct()) ?>,
        "jsonConfig": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>,
        "jsonSwatchConfig": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsonSwatchConfig() ?>
    }}'>
</div>
```

2. Then, after this, I've triggered 'contentUpdated' inside my list.phtml template under Magento_Catalog/templates. It will render swatches on both initial page load and on the ajax page load. I did it like this:

```
$('div[class*="swatch-opt-"]').trigger('contentUpdated');
```

Your case might be different, but at least it might help you to investigate further.